# How to check for a zer0 timestamp in MySql?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a MySql table with some fields which are of type `TIMESTAMP`.

I want to detect those which are "invalid" (have never had data inserted and there is no default).

Is there some MySql constant I can use ? e.g `SELECT .. WHERE timestamp_column=INVALID_DATE_TIME`

Or should I just compare with "0000-00-00 00:00:00 "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there would be either `null` or `"0000-00-00 00:00:00"` if you have not considered this at the time of insert

Answer (score 2):

You cannot store invalid dates into **TIMESTAMP** column. The TIMESTAMP column always requires a valid date.

Only NULL value may help you.

Comment: +1 @devart SO, if I have never inserted a value into that column, I can `SELECT ... WHERE column=NULL`?

Comment: Yes, you can SELECT ... WHERE column=NULL, but result may be empty. I meant you can insert NULL value to say it was invalid.